# Is it possible to split Cuda jobs between GPU & CPU?

Tags: cuda

I'm having a bit of problems understanding how or if its possible to share a work load between a gpu and cpu.  I have a large log file that I need to read each line then run about 5 million operations on(testing for various scenarios).  My current approach has been to read a few hundred lines, add it to an array and then send it to each GPU, which is working fine but because there is so much work per line and so many lines it takes a long time.  I noticed that while this is going on my CPU cores are basically doing nothing. I'm using EC2, so I have 2 quad core Xeon & 2 Tesla GPUs, one cpu core reads the file(running the main program) and the GPU's do the work so I'm wondering how or what can I do to involve the other 7 cores into the process?

I'm a bit confused at how to design a program to balance the tasks between GPU/CPU because they both would finish the jobs at different times so I couldn't just send it to them all at the same time.  I thought about setting up a queue(I'm new to c, so not sure if this is possible yet) but then is there a way to know when a GPU job is completed(since I thought sending jobs to Cuda was asynchronous)? I kernel is very similar to a normal c function so converting it for cpu usage is not problem just balancing the work seems to be the issue. I went though 'Cuda by example' again but couldn't really find anything referring to this type of balancing.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the key is to create a multithreaded app, following all the common practices for that, and have two types of worker threads. One that does work with the GPU and one that does work with the CPU. So basically, you will need a thread pool and a queue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

The queue can be very simple. You can have one shared integer that is the index of the current row in the log file. When a thread is ready to retrieve more work, it locks that index, gets some number of lines from the log file, starting at the line designated by the index, then increases the index by the number of lines that it retrieved, and then unlocks.

When a worker thread is done with one chunk of the log file, it posts its results back to the main thread and gets another chunk (or exits if there are no more lines to process).

The app launches some combination of GPU and CPU worker threads to utilize all available GPUs and CPU cores.

One problem you may run into is that if the CPU is busy, performance of the GPUs may suffer, as slight delays in submitting new work or processing results from the GPUs are introduced. You may need to experiment with the number of threads and their affinity. For instance, you may need to reserve one CPU core for each GPU by manipulating thread affinities.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say line-by-line may be you can split the jobs across 2 different process -
One CPU + GPU Process
One CPU process that utilized remaining 7 cores

You can start of each process with different offsets - like 1st process reads the lines 1-50, 101-150 etc while the 2nd one reads 51-100, 151-200 etc

This will avoid you the headache of optimizing CPU-GPU interaction